# parsing a huge text file and obtaining next and previous lines after match

Tags: python

I have a huge text file of some 500 MB as,i need to print the lines matching the input, along with the previous 3 lines and next 3 lines.

My text file looks like:

```
...
...
...
benz is a nice car
...
...
...
its also said benz is a safe car
...
...
...
```

If the user input as 'benz' then it should print the 3 lines before and after of the matching, for every individual matches.

My code:-

```
users= raw_input('enter the word:')
with open('mytext.txt',rb) as f:
     for line if f:
         if users in line:
            print line(i-3)
            print line
            print line(i+3)
```

But errors as i not defined

Comment: As suggested by @Lutz Horn, grep is a fine choice. Do it yourself, and you'll tie yourself up with unnecessary code and probably get it to perform like a dog with no legs. Grep has been around "a while". It is designed to search text files. If you are searching text and grep does all that you need, it is an excellent choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
$ grep -C 3 benz mytext.txt
```

Comment: i wanted it in python!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: how can i implement it in python?because its going to be a part of my code!please help

Comment: Instead of the both `-A 3` and `-B 3` option you could use the combination of both with `-C 3`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small function that might be useful for your case:

```
from collections import deque

def search_cont(filename, search_for, num_before, num_after):
    with open(filename) as f:
        before_lines = deque(maxlen=num_before)
        after_lines = deque(maxlen=num_after+1)
        for _ in range(num_after+1):
            after_lines.append(next(f))
        while len(after_lines)>0:
            current_line = after_lines.popleft()
            if search_for in current_line:
                print("".join(before_lines))
                print(current_line)
                print("".join(after_lines))
                print("-----------------------")
            before_lines.append(current_line)
            try:
                after_lines.append(next(f))
            except StopIteration:
                pass
```

For your example you call it like

```
search_for = raw_input('enter the word:')
search_cont('mytext.txt', search_for, 3, 3)
```

This solution has no upper bound for the size of your file (except you have really long lines) as there are never more than 7 lines in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `grep` from python:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["grep" "-A" "3" "-B" "3" "benz" "mytext.txt"])
```